# Is ok to not "join" with multiprocessing, when tasks are expected to run forever?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand how multiprocessing works in python, I came to a use case where I want read some messages from a queue system and write them to a database.

Is it ok not to use `p.join()` in the final loop? This is because I see is a lot faster when I omit this join;
or what could be its consequences?

I don't have any more code bellow that.

```py
def process():
    while True:
       message = read_from_queue()
       write_to_database(message)


for _ in range(4):
    p = Process(target=process)
    p.start()
```

Comment: `join()` is when you actually wait for results to come back. If you don't call it, your program may exit before all the work has actually been done.

Comment: You should `join` after the loop in which you do `start` (in a separate loop), not inside it. Append the `Process` instances to a list, so that you can loop again, doing `join`.

Comment: The thing is, a have a While loop that nevers ends, so that outside join should never happen

Comment: Specifically, I would suggest: you can do `procs = [Process(target=process) for _ in range(4)]` then `for p in procs: p.start()` then `for p in procs: p.join()`

Comment: Okay, just seen the infinite loop. Well I don't understand how your code would ever run anything in parallel if you have a `join` inside the loop that has the `start`. When you call `join`, then it will wait until the process is finished.

Comment: Edited the title to make that (tasks expected to run forever) part of the question, since it changes the answers substantially.

Comment: Yea, exactly that is why I want to know if is ok to remove that join because I wont ever pass the while loop (sorry, just understanding this), and I wont have any problems with a zombie process or similar

Comment: (that said, in general, this strikes me as using multiprocessing in a manner well outside its design parameters; _even if it works perfectly today_, I would worry about that no longer being true in the future -- memory leaks or similar consequences are not inconceivable; as a general rule -- not just for Python -- only documented semantics can be relied on to hold true on an ongoing basis as software changes over time)

Comment: If you don't call `join`, the operating system will continue to track the process. If you do that a lot, there is a chance that you will eat up process resources. when your parent program exits, it calls join. If your child processes last forever, the parent doesn't full exit either. You can set the `Process.daemon` flag, but in that case your parent process will terminate the child processes on exit.

Comment: What could be a suggestion to avoid this? Start manually different instances of my application?

Comment: I think what you are doing now is okay. You start 4 processes and when your top script exits, it does a join in the background. What seems to be missing here is management of these child processes - how are they terminated? - but since this is a simple example, I wouldn't expect that extra detail anyway.

Comment: They could be manually stopped or by a system shot down, but both functions somehow are safe if they get interrupted while reading/writing a transaction

Answer (score 1):

Python tries to `join` all non-daemon child processes before closing using the `atexit` module (daemons are `terminate()`ed). If the child runs forever, then the parent will too. If the parent is doing nothing but waiting on a `join`, it won't be consuming much in the way of system resources, so it's not a big deal. The problem comes in when you have to shut down your system / program. IMAO it's always best to provide a smooth shutdown mechanism for your programs, and using `signal.signal` to set up handlers or some sort of semaphore from the main process for smooth shutdown is a great idea. All that said, if you know your database access is resilient to interrupted writes (eg via journaling), you may choose to stick to simpler code, and just kill python without any grace. All modern OS's will do a good job cleaning up after terminated processes.

As for speed, it sounds like your previous code perhaps looked a bit like this?

```
for _ in range(4):
    p = Process(target=process)
    p.start()
    p.join() # <- putting join next to start is usually an anti-pattern because it basically precludes parallel-processing.
```

This means you wouldn't actually ever have 4 child processes running because it would wait for the first one to finish before creating or starting any more (which would never happen because it runs forever). By taking it out, you leave the `join`ing for after you've started all 4 child processes (which you can leave to the automatic join, or do by yourself in another loop).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, the join was like that and with another loop appending all process to a list, but that loop would never be reached since the "Process" loop never ends. Sorry to ask, is there any understandable resources on the signal.signal? Sounds like a good idea but couldn't find a good explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigoA [Things I Wish They Told Me About Multiprocessing in Python](https://www.cloudcity.io/blog/2019/02/27/things-i-wish-they-told-me-about-multiprocessing-in-python/) has a little section on signal handling, and [Graceful exit with Python multiprocessing](https://the-fonz.gitlab.io/posts/python-multiprocessing/) goes into way more depth

Comment: They both talk about things from a more "production code" standpoint. I come from a research background, and more often take the position: "good enough is good enough" I don't spend nearly as much time making my code bulletproof, because I'm likely the only one who will ever run it. Still... they have good thoughts on how do do multiprocessing robustly.